# Passing member functions with variadic template arguments to variadic constructors

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I can't figure out how to pass member function with variadic template arguments to `std::thread` constructor. I have a method that receives function and its arguments and need to pass them to other method which is invoked in new thread and calls passed function there.
Here is simplified version:

```
class Test
{
public:
    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    void Run(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        std::thread t(&Test::Operation, this, f, args...); // how???
        t.detach();
    }

    template<typename Function, typename... Args>
    void Operation(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
    {
        f(args...);
    }
};

Test test;
test.Run([](const std::string& msg) { std::cout << msg; }, "Hi!");
```

There is something wrong in passing arguments this way, I get the following error: 'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 4 arguments. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just use function overloading?

Comment: @vonbrand I need to execute large number of various functions in similar scenario so I want to minimize code for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is that when you pass `&Test::Operation` to the thread constructor, it can't deduce the template parameters for `&Test::Operation`. (If you want to understand why this deduction cannot be done, you should probably ask a separate question.) The point is that you need to explicitly specify the template arguments for `&Test::Operation`.

This will look like this:

```
template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void Run(Function&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    std::thread t(&Test::Operation<std::decay_t<Function>, std::decay_t<Args>...>,
                  this, std::forward<Function>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    t.detach();
}
```

I added perfect forwarding for you: it's important because you don't want to perform an unnecessary copy, right?

But why do we need the `decay_t`? It's because the thread constructor decays its arguments before storing copies of them in the new thread's internal storage, so, for example, if you pass in `"Hi!"`, then the deduced type is `const char (&)[4]`, but it will become a `const char*` once decayed, and the decay is irreversible, so `Test::Operation` must not be expecting a `const char (&)[4]`, which cannot be initialized from the decayed `const char*`. So `Test::Operation` must be specified to take the decayed type.

You also probably want perfect forwarding during the actual invocation.

Link: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9d04c03a3758b51

Comment: Definitely what I was looking for. Thanks for explanation!